# execSQL(); method not working properly. how can i make it work?

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am trying to create a new table but as soon as i run the app it shows me an error that something is not right in the db.execSQL();

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Username TEXT, Password TEXT");
}
```

Comment: Change to `, Password TEXT)")`;

Comment: thanks now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code :

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Username TEXT, Password TEXT)”);
```

}

There is an issue in SQL query statement, I hope it helps you. Thanks